# Random disconnection of mouse

Tags: windows-10, usb, motherboard, mouse

Currently I own a Dragonwar Leviathan Laser Gaming Mouse (Model: ELE-G1). It randomly disconnects and reconnects itself.

I have seen solutions for it but none seem to work. I think that I need to upgrade my firmware (which I hope, should resolve the problem). I installed Piriform Speccy to get the model number of the motherboard, but when I head to the official site of Gigabyte I am presented with "my motherboard model" + " some suffix". So I am confused on which driver belongs to my motherboard.

Note:

1. I have disabled automatic USB suspend (which didn't work)
2. Tried another mouse but the problem still persists.
3. I have attached some pictures for the model number and the numerous search results which appear for my motherboard

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9p8AiUKhNWJSTN2VGhjLW1NbkE

[image]

Comment: What your google drive link contains?

Comment: its just a screenshot of the info of the motherboard .

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of issue I follow some steps to discard point of fail:

1) hardware

- test the device in another computer with only same operational system to discard a fail in the device unit, if it continues fail in other computer maybe de device unit has a hardware fail, if not go to next step;
- test the same device in different usb ports in the same computer, if the same happpens in all of them is not a problem in isolated usb port, now if it works fine in some of them have someone with different details (max power enabled in these ports or more clean usb connect pins that could be doing this fail);
- another point of hardware (is software but I like to include it in hardware) are the bios usb sets like legancy usb support and for usb 3.0 the speed and also the power enable while sleeping in some port in case of laptops. Try different sets when no one of last tries not work.
- one thing that I really never trust are the usb cable in any device. I fixed in all my life a lot of usb device issues changing the usb cabe because they broken (a lot of times are little brokens) inside where we don't see and start signal fail and bad power conduction. And to fix a bad mouse cable depends if you have warranty or if it gone if exist a unit of it to replace.

2) Software

In this case only a device firmware upgrade could fix some issue that the manufacturer found.

I hope give you some new idea if you didn't have already to help you drive your fix.
Good luck in your fix.